# How to use spring xml for collection of primitives?

Tags: spring, collections

```
<bean id="library" class="org.yatin.learning.Library">
    <property name="books">
        <list>
            <ref bean ="spring"/>
            <ref bean ="java"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Above is ok in case collection is a list og objects… what if it is a list of primitive types???

Answer (score 0):

**This looks like:**

List of Integers:

```
<util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
    <value>1</value>
    <value>1</value>
</util:list>
```

List of Strings:

```
<util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList" value-type="java.lang.String">
    <value>This</value>
    <value>That</value>
</util:list>
```

And so on.